# Read csv into dictionary with 2 keys per value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a csv file structure as follows:

```
+------+------+--------+
| name | pos  |  eff   |
+------+------+--------+
| a    |    1 |   10.0 |
| b    |    1 |     42 |
| c    |    1 |    123 |
+------+------+--------+
```

the keys value pair should look like this, using a tuple:

```
hash = ('a', 1): [10.0]
```

so far I have

```
import csv

csv_dictionary = {}

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        csv_dictionary[row['name']]= row['eff']
        csv_dictionary[row['pos']] = row['eff']
```

but this seems to give multiple keys per value.
Do csv files require unique elements in each column?

How can I go about making a tuple for `name` and `pos` associate with `eff`?

Comment: `dictionary[(row['name'], row['pos'])] = row['eff']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the code manually, you will see that `csv_dictionary[row['name']]` and `csv_dictionary[row['pos']]` are independent statements. In your example, if you run the code on row 0, it gives you a `csv_dictionary` of `{"a": "10.0", "1": "10.0"}`.

If you want tuples as keys, you need to use a tuple: `csv_dictionary[row['name'], row['pos']] = row['eff']`